# Jetpack compose doesn't recompose on mutableStateOf change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I wanted to build a very simple demo. A button which you can click, and it counts the clicks.

Code looks like this:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private var clicks = mutableStateOf(0)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
           Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                NewsStory(clicks.value) { onClick() }
           }
        }
    }

    private fun onClick() {
        clicks.value++
    }
}

@Composable
fun NewsStory(clicks: Int, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
        Button(onClick = onClick) {
            Text("Clicked: $clicks")
        }
    }
}
```

From my understanding this should be recomposed everytime the button is clicked, as `clicks` is changed.

But it does not work, any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm on `androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-beta01`, kotlin 1.5.10 and compose version 1.0.0-beta08

Comment: Code should work, try to clean your project and rebuild it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the "remember" keyword for the recomposition to happen each time, as explained here: https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/general/state/

In short, your composable would look like this:

```
    @Composable
fun NewsStory (){
val clickState = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
Column (modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
        Button(
            onClick = { clickState.value++ }) {
        }
        Text("Clicked: $clickState.value.toString()")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You put the `val clickState = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }` in the composable, is this a requirement?
In my code, the `clickState` is in the Activity, is this also a possibility? If I were to use a ViewModel, where would I put that?

Comment: The "remember" keyword only works in Composables. If you were to use a viewModel, you would pass it as an argument to your Composable, like in this example:  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state?authuser=1#viewmodel-state